# How do you end the tutorial campaign scenario

Tags: ultimate-space-commando

I started a campaign, played the first tutorial scenario, looted a base dry, explored everything, and then... I don't see that I can end the scenario to proceed with the campaign. I think I've clicked practically everything on the screen. All I've found is how to exit to the main menu.

**How can I get out of the scenario to proceed with the campaign? Is this a bug?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the elevator in the upper left corner with all your men! You can always press 'T' for objectives.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Ya, the tutorial windows had told me to go there, and I did, but it looked like a useless square room and I got to searching the rest of the place. The objective said there was no objective, so it seemed like time to go home.